# What happens when a question's solution requires an underlying question to be answered?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

Scenario:

An answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176610/52894) exists for [Why does my Python background process end when SSH session is terminated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167972/52894). However, the reason the answer works is unknown, and it led to another question ([What is the difference between letting nohup append to 'nohup.out' and explicitly redirecting it to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176674/52894)).

What happens when an answer has a working implementation, but the reason the implementation works is unknown (and leads to another question)?

- Do I mark the original question as a duplicate, and link to the underlying question?
- Do I accept the solution that works, but link to the underlying question (and where do I put that link?)
- Do I wait for the underlying question to be answered, and write up an answer for the original question based on the answer to the underlying question?
- Something else?